# Flutter: add data to Map (instead of replacing data)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The following transaction completely replaces the data in a Firestore Map when run:

```
DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await tx.get(docRef); // doc Snapshot
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    await tx.update(
      docRef,
        <String, dynamic>{
          'Users': {
            'user.uid': {'name': user.displayName, 'date': DateTime.now()},
              }
            },
          );
```

What would be the correct way to add to a map instead of replacing the existing data, the same way **FieldValue.arrayUnion** works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already fetched the data you could take the map out from the snapshot, replace the data there and call the update with the altered map.